# jquery - Finding nested Gridview and controls in it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, nested

Need help in finding nested Gridview and controls present in it for e.g. label
using jquery

I am in middle of doing calculations below is the jquery code.

```
$("#<%=gvSupplierList.ClientID %>").each(function () {

    //hardcoded control id of parent gridview
    $(this).find('span[id$="gvSupplierList_lblsizeofopt_0"]').text('0.01');

    //hardcoded control id of child/nested gridview
    $("#gvSupplierList_gvCustomerList_0 > tbody > tr").each(function () {

        //hardcoded control id of child/nested control 
        $(this).find('input[id$="gvSupplierList_gvCustomerList_0_txtsizeofopt_0"]').val();

    });

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FindControl to navigate up the Control Tree and locate the correct TextBox in the Rows of the Child GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewParent" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewChild" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= ((GridView)GridViewParent.Rows[1].FindControl("GridViewChild")).Rows[2].FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>").val("TextBox is found!");
</script>
```

In this snippet the TextBox in row 1 of the parent and row 2 of the child is located and the text set.

Or if you know both the rows in jQUewry you can also do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var parentRow = 3;
    var childRow = 5;

    $('#<%= GridViewParent.ClientID %> table').each(function (index, element) {
        if (index == parentRow) {
            $('#' + element.id + ' input[type="text"]').each(function (indexNested, elementNested) {
                if (indexNested == childRow) {
                    $(this).val("TextBox is found!")
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thing is I do not know which row it would be. Let me explain that scenario again in better way.                                                                   function will execute from text box in nested grid which should trigger to calculate all textboxes in that same nested grid and add up to the total in the label present in parent grid. Hope it helps in making things more clear, I know what logic is but I am finding it hard to use jquery syntax to implement it.       Thanks for your help.